# Change url city name from string

Tags: string, url

I have a url below:

```
string CityName = "NewYork";

var url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=6b87pfhmjb7ydj6w596fujpu";
```

I want to change url's "London" with string CityName".

I tried below to solve this problem however it has still syntax error.

```
string CityName = "NewYork";

var url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q="CityName "&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=6b87pfhmjb7ydj6w596fujpu";
```

So how can i integrated string cityname in the middle of url link ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What environment you're in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this,

```
var url = 'http://q="' + CityName + '"+&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=6b87pfhmjb7ydj6w596fujpu';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    var CityName = "NewYork";

var url = "http://q='"+ CityName+ "'&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=6b87pfhmjb7ydj6w596fujpu";
alert(url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
var CityName = "NewYork";

var url = 'http://q="' + CityName + '"+&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=6b87pfhmjb7ydj6w596fujpu';
```